# I need to get the name of 3 managers using sub queries the result should be 3 rows: Name, last name and salary

Tags: sql, subquery

1. get the name, last name and salary of the manager who has the greatest salary and  who was born the same week day that more employees joined the company.
2. the the name and last name and salary pf the manager with more male employees.
3. the the name and last name and salary pf the manager with more female employees.

**table name = empleados**

idemp is employee id
idjefe is manager id
dianacimiento is  birthday
diaingreso is first day on the company
salario is salary
sexo is gender

![this should be the result][1]

```
NOMBRE         APELLIDO          SALARIO                                                            
-------------- -------------- ----------                                                            
PUBLIS         MANLIO            1350000                                                            
GABRIEL        NOLOSA             990000                                                            
JAIME          ROSETTI           1400000
```

**Attempt:**

```
select nombre,apellido,salario
from empleados
where salario = (
      select max(salario)
      from empleados
      where idemp = (
            select idemp
            from empleados
            where idjefe = (
                  select idjefe,count(idemp),salario
                  from empleados
                  group by idjefe, salario
                  order by count(idemp) desc
                  where rownum < 2))
           )
     )            
)
/
```

Comment: We need both example table data and the matching expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: It would also be a good idea to show your attempts as this [reads like homework.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2221001)